# If statement inside "value" property of html input box

Tags: javascript, html, hook

I have an `<input>` box below that currently works. I want to know if im able to place an `if` statement inside the `value` property.

```
             <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                id="name"
                value={stockName.toUpperCase()}
                onChange={event => {
                  // Check that no numbers have been added 
                  const { value } = event.target;

                  if (/[^a-z]/gi.test(value)) { // Check that only letters are in the search
                    setError("Symbols should only contain letters!");
                  } else {
                    setError(null);
                    let uppercaseValue =  value.toUpperCase(); // Make sure its uppercase 
                    setStockName(uppercaseValue);
                  }
                }}/>
```

For example I want to do something like this in the `value` property.

```
         value={event => {

              if (symbolSearchBool){ // If true 
                return symbolSearch // Set value to this, but still allow user to change it if needed
              }
              else { 
                return stockName.toUpperCase() // Set value to whatever user types in
              }
            }}
```

Is there a way to do this?

I am using useState for

```
      const [stockName, setStockName] = useState(); // Hold user input for stock Symbol 
      const [error, setError] = useState(null); // Hold error state based on poor user input
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are suggesting is possible using a [ternary-operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

The reason why your example does not work is because you are declaring a function. Typically a React component's `value` property does not attempt to be called (as a function), but rather is expected to be the value itself.

That is not to say that it couldn't. It's just against convention, and you should expect third-party components to *not* attempt to call your `value` property.

---

#### Solution

```
 <input
   type="text"
   name="name"
   id="name"
   value={symbolSearchBool ? symbolSearch : stockName.toUpperCase()}
   onChange={event => { ... }}
/>
```

Notice here the use of the ternary operator here, with the syntax:
`condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse`

You can read this as the following:

```
if (condition) {
  return exprIfTrue;
} else {
  return exprIfFalse;
}
```